# eventDrop in fullCalendar

Tags: jquery, html, css, fullcalendar

I am new to fullCalendar and am facing issues in eventDrop callback function.
As in the docs ,dayDelta and minDelta returns no of days and no of mins moved .
But my case , its returns something else.

Here is my code,

```
eventDrop: function(event,dayDelta,minuteDelta,allDay,revertFunc) {
     // alert("Event Title" + event.title);
      alert("Duration Moved "+ dayDelta);
      alert("Minutes Moved " + minuteDelta);
     if(!confirm("Are you sure want to move ?"))
      revertFunc();
}
```

when i try to move events to another date, it alerts

[image: MinsMovedAlert]

[image: DaysMovedAlert]

Can anyone please let me know where the mistake is .

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be using fullCalendar v 2.x but referring to docs from 1.x

2.x ->

```
function( event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view ) { }
```

1.x ->

```
function( event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view ) { }
```

Check out the current fullCalendar eventDrop [callback docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/eventDrop/)